# grep with escape character

Tags: python, grep, subprocess

I need to find exact string from a file. Assume simple text file contains 3 lines of text

```
SILVERGOLD-A
SILVERGOLD-AMY
SILVERGOLD-ACB
```

and I need to find exact string `"SILVERGOLD-A"`.  I am using following command in the terminal:

```
cat text.txt | grep "\bSILVERGOLD-A\b"
```

and I am able to successfully get only `"SILVERGOLD-A"` as output. However, it is not working in Python with `subprocess.POpen`. My code looks like:

```py
cmd1 = ['cat', text.txt]
cmd2 = ['grep', find_string] ==> Where String is find_string = '\'\b' + find_string + '\'\b'
ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
grep = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdin=ps.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ps.stdout.close()
print("grepout {0}".format(grep.communicate()))
```

But I continue to get empty grep results. Any clue or help?

And if I remove `\b` from string then I do get all string matching (even partial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to escape `\` in your `find_string`, so that it reads `'\\b'`. Alternatively you can use r-string `r'\b'`.

Also I think you need to get rid of `\'` in your `find_string`. If it was intended to quote the regex, I guess `Popen()` automatically quote the args for you. The following [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) seems relevant:

> `['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]`
>
> ... arguments that need quoting or backslash escaping when used in the shell (such as filenames containing spaces or the echo command shown above) are single list elements.

So, for me `cmd2 = ['grep', r'\b' + 'SILVERGOLD-A' + r'\b']`  seems to work. Try this.

As a side note, `grep` does not need a stdin if you provide the input file; i.e., you can simplify the code as follows:

```py
import subprocess

cmd2 = ['grep', r'\b' + 'SILVERGOLD-A' + r'\b', 'text.txt']
grep = subprocess.Popen(cmd2, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print("grepout {0}".format(grep.communicate()))
```